# How to render different pages in 1 WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently having issues with rendering different screens in 1 window (only 1 screen displayed in the window at a time).

The solution i want to achieve in my WPF application:

- 1 Window (all screens must be within the same screen)
- 3 different screens
- when something is selected on the 3th screen (button), the first screen shows up again

The first and the second screen were loading up successfully but i was unable to open the 3th screen. Since then i have been trying several things but was unable to come up with a solution.

*The application structure looks like the the following:*

Main Screen (With a button) --> When clicked on the button 2ndscreen replace the 1st screen. The 2nd screen holds yet another button, when clicked shows the 3th and final screen.

I cannot seem to be able to open this 3th page.

What i have tried so far without any success

- navigation window (redirection with the navigationService always yields a null exception)
- frame (when i open the second frame the content of the first frame is still there, a refresh or content clear did not work to render only the second screen).

Best regards.

Comment: What is a screen?  I don't know of any control named screen?   Post the code you tried.